# coordinator's under supervision devices

Tags: word-choice

Suppose I have a coordinator which manages and supervises several devices. In fact these devices are under the supervision of this coordinator. We want to mention these devices.

What is the best phrase for referring to these devices? Is it correct to say:

> coordinator's under supervision devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the wording you have, it would make the meaning clearer if you used hyphenation:

> coordinator's under-supervision devices

This makes it obvious that *under-supervision* is being used adjectivally to modify *devices*.

---

However, you could also keep those exact words, but reorder them:

> devices under coordinator's supervision

---

Also note that you'll probably want to use an article or demonstrative in front of *coordinator*: ***(a / the / this / that)*** *coordinator's*.

Comment: Thank you. Can I also use "overseen"? I mean: *coordinator's overseen devices*. If so, which one is a better choice?

Comment: @pablo That would also work. I can't tell you which is *better*, however. If you're asking my purely personal opinion, I might drop mention of the coordinator and just say *managed devices*. (That's also a standard technical term in IT.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "under supervision" can be simplified to be simply *supervised*. So, you could refer to them as:

> the coordinator's supervised devices

Or, if it's obvious that you're talking about the devices supervised by that coordinator, you can leave out the posessive (making a much simpler phrase):

> the supervised devices